# How to include Concern inside DeviseMailer - strange name_error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using engines inside my Rails 7 app. I've got Core engine where I can find a devise mailer (from devise_invitable gem). Think there is only 1 Devise application mailer possible, and I don't need a copy anything inside `devise.rb`.

My goal is to to override `invitation_instructions` method from Core engine into `PaymentProcess` engine. To do that I'll use `concerns`, so in a nutshell:

- add a devise mailer concern inside payment_engine and include it to devise mailer inside payment_process/engine.rb initializer
- overwrite invitation_instructions, but keep super when a user is not a payment_process user.

Here is my code:

`engines/core/app/mailers/devise_application_mailer.rb`

```
class DeviseApplicationMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def invitation_instructions(recipient, *args)
    account, = recipient.accounts
    scope = 'devise.mailer.invitation_instructions'
    @invited_by_text = invited_by_text(account, recipient.invited_by, scope)
    mail = super
    mail.subject = I18n.t('subject_with_account', account_name: account.name, scope:) if account.present?
    mail
  end
  # other stuff (...)
end
```

`engines/payment_process/app/mailers/concerns/devise_application_mailer_concern.rb`:

```
module DeviseApplicationMailerConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def invitation_instructions(resource, *args)
      if resource.is_a?(PaymentProcess)
        recipient, customer = resource
        scope = 'devise.mailer.invitation_instructions'
        @invited_by_text = invited_by_text(customer, recipient.invited_by, scope)
        mail = super
        mail.subject = I18n.t('subject', scope:) if customer.present?
        mail
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So now I want to include everything inside engine initializer:

`engines/payment_process/lib/payment_process/engine.rb`

```
module PaymentProcess
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    engine_name 'payment_process'
    isolate_namespace PaymentProcess

      # some other stuff

    config.to_prepare do
      # some other stuff
      Devise::Mailer.include(PaymentProcess::DeviseApplicationMailerConcern)
    end
  end
end
```

And all of these produces me an error of:

> block in class:Engine': uninitialized constant PaymentProcess::DeviseApplicationMailerConcern (NameError)
> Devise::Mailer.include(PaymentProcess::DeviseApplicationMailerConcern)

I've tried to `require` file path inside the engine but it won't help. I also tried to include concern directly inside the `engines/core/app/mailers/devise_application_mailer.rb` but I'm getting the same error.

What did I missed? or maybe it's not possible with to include anything to Devise ?